# How does Chrome categorize CSS rules?

Tags: css

The Chrome web inspector has atleast 3 ways of showing CSS rules.

Normal, normal with a line through, and opaque.  Here is a picture of the 3.

[image]

Comment: As a side note: There's also a 4th state, strike-trough and grayed out. it's used for rules that are unknown and therefore not applied, you'll see them mostly because of browser specific css for the other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly I believe that means its inherited from a parent element.  Strikethrough means it was overridden by another style.